# Install rvm at a specific version

Tags: ruby, rvm

According to the docs, I can specify the `--branch` option to point to an owner and branch when installing RVM. If I wanted to install specifically `1.25.15`, is there a way to do that? I see that versions are tagged on the git repo, so I could theoretically fork and checkout a branch at that tag and point to it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Keep in mind, I'm talking about the version of rvm, not the version of Ruby.

Comment: had you try `--branch 1.25.15`?

Answer (score 1):

which docs did you read? I just read http://rvm.io/rvm/install and found this:

> Installing a specific version:
>
> ```
>    user$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --version latest
>    user$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --branch [owner/][repo]
> ```

but it should be also enough to run:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 1.25.15
```